# Based on different resolutions, how to make design responsiveness using bootstrap grid system?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 data-one">
      <one />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 dashboard-two">
      <two />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-4 dashboard-three">
      <three />
    </div>
  </div>
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .data-one {
  }
  .data-two {
  }
  .data-three {
  }
}
```

Using bootstrap grid system, how to make responsiveness. like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xkPE.png)

and i am also having issue like, when elements touch each other, getting collide(intersecting each other).

Any example will be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on a Bootstrap row with three items, using `col-md-12` as one of the classes doesn't make much semantic sense. Essentially because a `col-12` is supposed to span the full-width. For a responsive Bootstrap design, it would be semantically correct to use `col-lg-4` for large screens, `col-md-4` for medium screens, and it will use `col-sm-4` for mobile devices like phones. I added `w-100` for 100% width and `text-center` to align text to the center.  See the changes I made below.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container w-100">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```